# JavaScript/Unity Reference Error: google is not defined

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

Working on a new game with Unity and JavaScript and I went to test it on my friend's PC. We both have the latest version of Unity, so it isn't a Unity update problem. The specific error is this

> An error occured running the Unity content on this page. See your
>   browser JavaScript console for more info. The error was:
>   ReferenceError: google is not defined

Anyone have some ideas of how to

- fix this for the future
- bypass it to test the game

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the problem was with adblock preventing loading the google Adsense. Disable adblock or change code so that it can be loaded without the ad module.

Answer (score -1):

Error you write is telling you the whole story itself. Some type of library "Google" is missing or not properly added or might be detach from your code while you transferring from one computer to other. Try to remove and add your library.